# Scala - Iterate Over Two Arrays

Tags: scala

How do you iterate over two arrays of the same size, accessing the same index each iteration The Scala Way™?

```
      for ((aListItem, bListItem) <- (aList, bList)) {
         // do something with items
      }
```

The Java way applied to Scala:

```
     for(i <- 0 until aList.length ) {
          aList(i)
          bList(i)
      }
```

Assume both lists are the same size.

Comment: What's the matter with what you're starting with?  If the problem is that it doesn't compile, just add definitions to the tuple: 'for ((aListItem:Int, bListItem:Int)...'

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17199534/406435

Comment: The Scala Way (TM) is not to use Arrays (which are mutable), but Lists, and these are inefficient for random access (i.e. by index). Anyway, whichever you use, the correct solution is buried in Rex Kerr's answer: `(aList, bList).zipped.foreach{ (a,b) => ??? }`. And yes it is efficient because it doesn't need to create tuples for every element (unlike `zip`).

Comment: I updated the answer to include timing information.  @LuigiPlinge - Zipped is the fast-yet-easy way to go if your arrays are _not_ primitives.  If they are, boxing overhead kills you.

Comment: Good point, thanks @Rex. That applies to Arrays only, not Lists or Vectors, since in the latter primitives are already boxed, right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**tl;dr**: There are trade-offs between speed and convenience; you need to know your use case to pick appropriately.

---

If you know both arrays are the same length and you don't need to worry how fast it is, the easiest and most canonical is to use `zip` inside a for-comprehension:

```
for ((a,b) <- aList zip bList) { ??? }
```

The `zip` method creates a new single array, however.  To avoid that overhead you can use `zipped` on a tuple which will present the elements in pairs to methods like `foreach` and `map`:

```
(aList, bList).zipped.foreach{ (a,b) => ??? }
```

Faster still is to index into the arrays, especially if the arrays contain primitives like `Int`, since the generic code above has to box them.  There is a handy method `indices` that you can use:

```
for (i <- aList.indices) { ??? }
```

Finally, if you need to go as fast as you possibly can, you can fall back to manual while loops or recursion, like so:

```
// While loop
var i = 0
while (i < aList.length) {
  ???
  i += 1
}

// Recursion
def loop(i: Int) {
  if (i < aList.length) {
    ???
    loop(i+1)
  }
}
loop(0)
```

If you are computing some value, rather than having it be a side effect, it's sometimes faster with recursion if you pass it along:

```
// Recursion with explicit result
def loop(i: Int, acc: Int = 0): Int =
  if (i < aList.length) {
    val nextAcc = ???
    loop(i+1, nextAcc)
  }
  else acc
```

Since you can drop a method definition in anywhere, you can use recursion without restriction.  You can add an `@annotation.tailrec` annotation to make sure it can be compiled down to a fast loop with jumps instead of actual recursion that eats stack space.

Taking all these different approaches to calculate a dot product on length 1024 vectors, we can compare these to a reference implementation in Java:

```
public class DotProd {
  public static int dot(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) s += a[i]*b[i];
    return s;
  }
}
```

plus an equivalent version where we take the dot product of the lengths of strings (so we can assess objects vs. primitives)

```
normalized time
-----------------
primitive  object  method
---------  ------  ---------------------------------
 100%       100%   Java indexed for loop (reference)
 100%       100%   Scala while loop
 100%       100%   Scala recursion (either way)
 185%       135%   Scala for comprehension on indices
2100%       130%   Scala zipped
3700%       800%   Scala zip
```

This is *particularly* bad, of course, with primitives!  (You get similarly huge jumps in time taken if you try to use `ArrayList`s of `Integer` instead of `Array` of `int` in Java.)  Note in particular that `zipped` is quite a reasonable choice if you have objects stored.

Do beware of premature optimization, though!  There are advantages to in clarity and safety to functional forms like `zip`.  If you always write while loops because you think "every little bit helps", you're probably making a mistake because it takes more time to write and debug, and you could be using that time optimizing some more important part of your program.

---

But, assuming your arrays are the same length is dangerous.  Are you *sure*?  How much effort will you make to be sure?  Maybe you shouldn't make that assumption?

If you don't need it to be fast, just correct, then you have to choose what to do if the two arrays are not the same length.

If you want to do something with all the elements up to the length of the shorter, then `zip` is still what you use:

```
// The second is just shorthand for the first
(aList zip bList).foreach{ case (a,b) => ??? }
for ((a,b) <- (aList zip bList)) { ??? }

// This avoids an intermediate array
(aList, bList).zipped.foreach{ (a,b) => ??? }
```

If you instead want to pad the shorter one with a default value, you would

```
aList.zipAll(bList, aDefault, bDefault).foreach{ case (a,b) => ??? }
for ((a,b) <- aList.zipAll(bList, aDefault, bDefault)) { ??? }
```

In any of these cases, you can use `yield` with `for` or `map` instead of `foreach` to generate a collection.

If you need the index for a calculation or it really is an array and you really need it to be fast, you will have to do the calculation manually.  Padding missing elements is awkward (I leave that as an exercise to the reader), but the basic form would be:

```
for (i <- 0 until math.min(aList.length, bList.length)) { ??? }
```

where you then use `i` to index into `aList` and `bList`.

If you *really* need maximum speed you would again use (tail) recursion or while loops:

```
val n = math.min(aList.length, bList.length)
var i = 0
while (i < n) {
  ???
  i += 1
}

def loop(i: Int) {
  if (i < aList.length && i < bList.length) {
    ???
    loop(i+1)
  }
}
loop(0)
```

Comment: Just small note that zipped is now deprecated. Instead one should use `lazyZip`. Like so `a.lazyZip(b).foreach{(a, b) => ??? }`

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
for ((aListItem, bListItem) <- (aList zip bList)) {
     // do something with items
}
```

Or with `map` like:

```
(aList zip bList).map{ case (alistItem, blistItem) => // do something }
```

---

**Updated:**

For iterating without creating an intermediates, you can try:

```
for (i <- 0 until xs.length) ... //xs(i) & ys(i) to access element
```

or simply

```
for (i <- xs.indices) ...
```

Comment: I think that added zip routine will hurt performance compared to the Java way.

Comment: Will have to see look at source to see if zip wraps or constructs a new array.

Comment: @BAR This might help in terms of performance consideration, but then again it depends on the use case and the compiler optimizaition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794823/is-scala-functional-programming-slower-than-traditional-coding

Comment: @BAR It does create an intermediate though.

Comment: zip creates a new array and copies data.  Need something just as fast as the usual way (by keeping index).

Comment: @BAR you can try the above instead, like Java getting the index and then iterating over

Comment: You could use `zipped` to avoid intermediate tuples creation [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17199579/406435).

Answer (score 1):

```
for {
    i <- 0 until Math.min(list1.size, list2.size)
 } yield list1(i) + list2(i)
```

Or something like that which checks bounds etc.

Comment: It would only check the list1 bounds. It could still blow up if the lists are not actually synced in sizing

Comment: This will _always_ go out of bounds because you used `to`, which is inclusive.

Comment: I had qualified in the answer that bounds needed to be checked but I updated it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
aList.indices foreach { i => 
   val (aListItem, bListItem) = (aList(i), bList(i))
   // do something with items
}
```

Comment: I like this very much.  Concise with Scala Syntax and Functionality.

Comment: This will throw an exception if `bList` is shorter than `aList`.

Comment: @RexKerr Both lists will be the same size.  Updating post to clarify.